# Can not change Display

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a login model with this property(mvc3, razor)

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[PasswordLength]
[Display(Name = "testname")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

and in my view

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
</div>
```

but do not show testname for

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password) show Password whats the problem?
```

when I remove

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[PasswordLength]
```

works fine but these two attributes are required for passwords fields.

Comment: What happens when you put the Display attribute first ahead of the other two?

Comment: Attribute order has no effect. You cannot count on order for anything. The `DataType` attribute is not required for passwords. The lack of knowing where `PasswordLength` comes from means I cannot test it however, your current setup works fine with mvc/razor so it appears that `PasswordLength` might be the culprit - though it would have to modify the ModelMetadata which isn't a common thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC targets 3.5 framework and Display is a .NET 4 attribute. You can use DisplayName attribute until the next release of ASP.NET MVC comes up.

See [Display Attribute Not Working](http://code.dortikum.net/2010/08/25/display-attribute-not-working-with-asp-net-mvc-2-rtm/) for details